# Ruby on Rails: Send Email when Creating a Record Doesn't Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

I'm wondering if someone could help me, within my Ruby on Rails application I am trying to get the system to send an email from a specific email address (Gmail) to a specific email address (Gmail), but for some reason the email does not send - but there is no error message.

Within my controller I have the following code to send an email when a new record is saved:

```
def create
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    if @email.save
   UserMailer.welcome_email.deliver
        redirect_to @email
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

This should call this Mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'abc@123.com'

  def welcome_email()
     mail(to: '123@abc.com', subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

My Application Mailer is as follows:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "abc@123.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

I then have the `welcome_email.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Thor Cinemas,!</h1>
     <p>
      You have successfully signed up to Thor Cinemas,
      your username is: .<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And a similar text version of the above.

For some reason this isn't working, I have the following in `$RAILS_ENV` (in `\config\environments`):

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'abc@123.com'}
```

The the below in `development.rb` of the same location:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = true    
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true      
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'example.com',
    user_name:            '123@abc.com', #replace with your username Eg. john.smith
    password:             'mypassword', #replace with your gmail password
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
end
```

And the below in `production.rb` in the same location:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port                 => 587,
     :user_name            => ENV['EMAIL_USER'],
     :password             => ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD'],
     :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }
end
```

And my `Gemfile` is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:         https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'validates_email_format_of'
gem "letter_opener", :group => :development
```

What I get in the `log` when creating a new record is as follows:

```
Started POST "/emails" for ::1 at 2016-06-08 19:41:10 +0100
Processing by EmailsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"5MZ3NNxbc5T5T/S9vLFK7EskqEGg4Xd2ZBimoQd3eXklW9HW+i+wxRryp    CFg//I5UUq7SnesIfPR0LDM4VFy7w==", "email"=>{"title"=>"qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq",     "text"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Email"}
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "emails" ("title", "text", "created_at",     "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["title", "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"], ["text",     ""], ["created_at", "2016-06-08 18:41:10.647620"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-08     18:41:10.647620"]]
  [1m[36m (173.0ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
  Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)
  Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)

UserMailer#welcome_email: processed outbound mail in 264.0ms

Sent mail to 123@abc.com (442.0ms)
Date: Wed, 08 Jun 2016 19:41:11 +0100
From: abc@123.com
To: 123@abc.com
Message-ID: <575866c716216_1fa44e42ca8808bd@mylaptop.mail>
Subject: Welcome to My Awesome Site
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_575866c714aa5_1fa44e42ca880795";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_575866c714aa5_1fa44e42ca880795
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Welcome to example.com, 
===============================================

You have successfully signed up to example.com,
your username is:.

To login to the site, just follow this link: http://localhost:3000/email/new.

Thanks for joining and have a great day!

----==_mimepart_575866c714aa5_1fa44e42ca880795
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <p>    
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link:     http://localhost:3000/email/new.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_575866c714aa5_1fa44e42ca880795--

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/emails/42
Completed 302 Found in 890ms (ActiveRecord: 174.0ms)


Started GET "/emails/42" for ::1 at 2016-06-08 19:41:11 +0100
Processing by EmailsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"42"}
  [1m[35mEmail Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "emails".* FROM "emails" WHERE     "emails"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 42]]
  Rendered emails/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 86ms (Views: 84.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/emails" for ::1 at 2016-06-08 19:41:13 +0100
Processing by EmailsController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mEmail Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "emails".* FROM "emails"[0m
  Rendered emails/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 88ms (Views: 87.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I am really confused as to why this isn't working, does anybody know?

Please note that I am using Windows 7 and running Rails 4.2.6.

Comment: which environment you are trying with, have you seen the logs if the mails are being created and not delivered

Comment: I am running in the development environment, and according to the logs the emails are being created

Comment: are you getting any Net::SMTPAuthenticationError or any error related to mailer credentials you are providing

Comment: I have just added what I can see in the log

Comment: @BenSmith You might want to change your email password though...

Comment: @HolgerJust thank you so much! I missed that one

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use deliver_now instead of deliver.

```
UserMailer.welcome_email.deliver_now
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have just tried this and it didn't make a difference

Comment: You may use this  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true.
after that you able to see any error for delivery reason on your email account.
and one more thing you need to set your email account for low secure apps also for sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

Mails are not delivered by default in development environment, Add this

```
      `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true`
```

in your development.rb to perform deliveries. if you are using Rails 4, use

```
 Notifier.welcome(User.first).deliver_now
```

As per the documentation, you can also use

```
 Notifier.welcome(User.first).deliver_now!
```

which Delivers an email without checking perform_deliveries and raise_delivery_errors, so use with caution.

**Edit:**

I see domain missing from your mailer setting in production.rb, use

```
 :domain               => "gmail.com",
```

Comment: Does it matter where in `development.rb` the line is added?

Comment: I would suggest to run the app in production environment and test this. confirm if the mail was created in production logs and also check the credentials directly if they are working.

Comment: I have just added `:domain               => "gmail.com",` into `production.rb` and `domain:                "gmail.com",` into `development.rb` but neither has worked

Comment: I have just added what I can see in the log into question

Comment: The code and logs seem proper. If you are  running in production env and mails are still not delivered, check for the setting with the mailer service provider you are using. Sometime you have to give access for third party apps to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114158/discussion-between-bijendra-and-ben-smith).